# Android Export Wizard Error

Tags: android

I want to create a signed apk, and eclipse shows me this dialog[image]

I'm using custom SDK ( not from google ).
Is anybody knows how to fix this problem ?

Comment: I convert my comment to answer. Please accept for future searchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error throws IDE. In your case - Eclipse.

Try to reinstall IDE and it's must worked.